# How can a wait function that uploads an image to firestore storage finish before running another function in android java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-storage

I want to make app upload many images to firestore storage and get all of the urls of those images and post it in firestore database by using java in android.

I have this function to post on database

```
  public void uploadFile(Map<String,Object> item , String phone){
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("Users").document().collection(phone).add(item)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Upload Complete",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                }
            });

}
```

The data is a hashmap of data I will post to the database. This data contains this information:

```
 Map<String,Object> data = new HashMap<>();
                      data.put("name" , name);
                      data.put("phone" , phone);
                      data.put("city" , city);
                      data.put("itemName" , itemName);
                      data.put("price" , price);
                      data.put("type" , type);
                      data.put("subtype" , subtype);
                      data.put("cond" , cond);
                      data.put("details" , details);
```

and I have this function to upload photo

```
public void upLoadImage(File data,Map<String,Object> list,int KEY){

   Uri file = Uri.fromFile(data);

   FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
   StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference().child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment());
   UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(file);
   
   uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
           url = "fails " + e.getMessage();

       }
   });
   uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

          storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                      if(KEY == 1){
                          list.put("image1",String.valueOf(uri));
                      }else if(KEY ==2){
                          list.put("image2",String.valueOf(uri));
                      }else if(KEY == 3){
                          list.put("image3",String.valueOf(uri));
                      }
              }
          });

       }
   });
```

this function take two argument data:

1. list that will push download url inside it
2. image file

I want to run it just like this

```
uploadImage(path1,data,1);
uploadImage(path2,data,2);
uploadImage(path3,data,3);
uploadfile()
```

This means that I want to upload image and complete then upload sec image and complete etc., then run uploadfile because my problem that uploadfile not wait upload image to complete.

Comment: You call the next one in onSuccess().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by write upload image like this

```
public void upLoadImage(String path,String path2, String path3,Map<String,Object> list,int KEY,String Auth){

  if(!path.equals("empty") && path != null){

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"path = " + path,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
      FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
      StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference().child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment());
      UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(file);
      uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
          @Override
          public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      });
      uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

              storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        if(KEY == 1 ){
                            list.put("image1",String.valueOf(uri));
                            upLoadImage(path2,"null",path3,list,2,Auth);

                        }
                        if(KEY == 2){
                            list.put("image2",String.valueOf(uri));
                            upLoadImage(path3,"null","null",list,3,Auth);
                        }
                        if(KEY == 3){
                            list.put("image3",String.valueOf(uri));
                            uploadFile(list,Auth);
                        }

                  }
              });

          }
      });
  }else {
      uploadFile(list,Auth);
  }
  
}
```